Precise key press event handling in console
I am coding this console app that updates the console every 500 millisecond. while it does that I want to set up a few key press actions. But using the following method is not precise and it misses a lot of key presses. Is it possible to have better precision?
I tried this:
void processInput() {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) & 0x8000) {
        x_position--;
        detectCollision(positions);
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) & 0x8000) {
        x_position++;
        detectCollision(positions);
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000) {
        rotate();
        detectCollision(positions);
    }
}

void setInterval(int interval) {
    while (true) {
        processInput();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(interval));
    }
}

int main()
{
    int interval = 1;
    thread periodicThread(setInterval, interval);
    periodicThread.join();
}


Your program processes input once every millisecond. Are you really missing many keypresses like that?

That's what is stumping me. The number of missed keys should not be this much. Can my cpu performance be the issue? I am using a i5-1335u. The threads seem to work pretty good in testing but maybe I am doing too much in a small timeframe? Could that be it?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput

@user15822796 Why don't you just use ReadConsoleInput ? It targets on the keyboard and mouse input of console.

It might be that your thread sleeps longer than expected. Calling timeBeginPeriod(1) at the start of the programm and timeEndPeriod(1) at the end has helped me in similar situations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod

the timeBeginPeriod thing works but not that precisely. It is much better though. I tried ReadConsoleInput but could not make it work-_-

@user15822796 would you check my answer please? If this is what your want, please accept it thx!

Not just ReadConsoleInput, you need to use KEY_EVENT_RECORD  struct from INPUT_RECORD struct.  It indicates that the event is a keyboard event. At this point, the Avant member will contain a base_evante_record structure that provides detailed information about keyboard events, such as whether a key was pressed, the number of times the key was repeated, the virtual keycode, the virtual scan code, the Unicod or Assi character representation, and the status of the control key.
See the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "GetStdHandle error\n";
        return 1;
    }

    const int maxEvents = 128;
    INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[maxEvents];
    DWORD cNumRead;

    while (true) {        
        if (!ReadConsoleInput(hStdin, irInBuf, maxEvents, &cNumRead)) {
            std::cerr << "ReadConsoleInput error\n";
            return 1;
        }

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < cNumRead; ++i) {
            if (irInBuf[i].EventType == KEY_EVENT) {
                KEY_EVENT_RECORD& ker = irInBuf[i].Event.KeyEvent;
                if (ker.bKeyDown) 
             { 
   std::cout << "Key Pressed: " << ker.wVirtualKeyCode << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


sorry for being a little late(I rage quit-_-). Your code works perfectly. Thank you.
